# Firebase Emulator Suite Admin SDK & FCM

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have a fairly complex solution built upon Firebase including Firebase Auth, Firestore, Storage, Functions, FCM, and a few Google APIs. (This is a mobile application). A lot of my logic is in Functions, specifically notifications using FCM. I noticed a lot of errors in my logs when running locally. I don't think it's hurting anything, but I was wondering if there was a way in Functions if I could determine that I was using the local emulator suite and not run certain logic. Or better yet, if I could still use outside logic within the functions running locally. The biggest one being FCM. I also use some of the Google APIs, but I get an error because the Firebase Emulator Suite uses a different projectId.